# popup window quickly disappears

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup window that it's supposed to show when I click certain button, everything seems to be ok but when I click the buttn the popup window quickly disappears, the weird thing is that I have another element like that in another section of my website and it works perfectly fine, but this one isn't working.

[opening popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRsJl.png)

[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAZC7.png)

Here's a link to a codepen for a better understanding https://codepen.io/CodingGilbert/pen/NzQmpL

html structure:

```
<main>
    <section class="products-container container">
      <nav class="categories">
        <span class="categories__link" id="accesories">Accesories</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Bottoms</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Dresses + Jumpsuits</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Outerwear</span>
        <span class="categories__link">Tops</span>
        <span class="categories__link">— Sale</span>
      </nav>
      <div class="products">
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori-jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Popup Shop Item -->

    <div class="popup-item">
      <div class="wrapper-item">
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img" class="wrapper-item__img">
        <div class="product-info">
          <h2 class="heading-secondary">Haori jacket</h2>
          <span class="product-info__price">$210.00</span>
          <p class="product-info__text">Sed ornare tellus non lectus blandit faucibus. Curabitur convallis nibh ut libero lobortis ullamcorper. Aliquam ornare risus in orci iaculis egestas. Vivamus varius ipsum eu leo ...</p>
          <div class="detail-group">
            <p class="detail-group__span">Size:</p>
            <select class="detail-group__size">
              <option value="">Select Size</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="detail-group">
            <p class="detail-group__span">Quantity:</p>
            <input class="detail-group__quantity" max="9999" min="1" value="1" type="number">
          </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn--form btn--form--shop">Add to cart</button>
            <a href="" class="btn-view">View Full Item</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="popup__close-icon" id="closeIcon">&times;</span>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
        <a href="" class="shop-item">
          <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/560c458be4b0af26f729d191/560c5de0e4b083d9c365515f/560d4f67e4b00b2c2a29ab00/1443712877696/lauren-winter-haori-jacket_0250.jpg?format=2500w" class="shop-item__img">
          <div class="quickview">
            <span class="quickview__icon">Quick View</span>
            <span class="quickview__info">Haori-jacket<br><span class="quickview__info--price">$210.00</span></span>
          </div>
        </a>
```

you need to set href attribute to `href="#"` because when you have `href=""` every time when you click on that element page are refreshing. Other option is to add return false to span onclick event:

```
$('.quickview__icon').click(function (){
    $('footer').css('display', 'none');
    $('.popup-item').css({'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Omg... I cannot believe something so simple was causing me so much trouble... But I'm supposed to be targeting only the "quickview" button, why  does this happen? And thank you btw, this fixed my issue, thank you so much!

Comment: it happens because `<span>` is inside `<a>` element and when you click span both events are triggernig